# Can I checkout a SVN repo from a Samba share on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, svn, smb

I have a few repos on a Windows network drive and I can check them out to my windows machine just fine.

The URL I'm using to checkout onto Windows is: `file:///Y:/project%20abc/svn/trunk`, where `Y:` is a mapped drive.

When it comes to Mac OS X I can browse the Samba share using Finder, that's fine. For the checkout I'm using the following: `svn co /Volumes/Share/Path/project\ abc/svn/trunk abc`. But I'm told that `'/Volumes/Share/Path/project\ abc/svn/trunk' does not appear to be a URL`.

I've also tried `svn co file://Volumes/Share/Path/project \abc/svn/trunk abc` but I'm told `Local URL 'file://volumes/Share/Path/project%20abc/svn/trunk' contains unsupported hostname`.

Can anyone suggest a fix? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the third slash as you omit the hostname as you say youself:

```
svn co file:///Volumes/Share/Path/project \abc/svn/trunk abc
```